# Reset Dropdown Selects when changing a hiring options

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, html, ajax

I have three selects that are dynamically populated after selecting an option from a select menu above it. If I select an option from the first select the second is populated as intended but if I change the option in the first, the options are appended to the preexisting options rather than the select being reset and then populated with the new data. I am sure that there is some sort of reload or reset method I can call when I want to flush the old data out of there 
before populating with the new data, I just can't find it.

Javascript

```
<script>
  $(function() {
    $("#service").change(function() {
      var service = $(this).val();
        $.ajax({
          type: "GET",
            url: "<?=Config::get('baseURL');?>getdata.php",
            data: { service: service },
            dataType: "json"
        }).done(function(reply) {
          console.log(reply);  
            $.each(reply, function(key, value) {   
                $('#category').append($('<option>', { value: value.value }).text(value.text)); 
            });
        });

    });
  });
  $(function () {
    $("#category").change(function() {
      var service = $("#service").val();
      var category = $(this).val();
      $.ajax({
          type: "GET",
          url: "<?=Config::get('baseURL');?>getdata.php",
          data: {
              service: service,
              category: category
          },
          dataType: "json"
      }).done(function (reply) {
          $.each(reply, function (key, value) {
              $("#subCategory").append($('<option>', {
                  value: value.value
              }).text(value.text));
          });
      });
    });
  })
</script>
```

This code works fine, but I how can I tweak it to flush the old data out of there if I change an option in preceding dropdown?

Comment: If the content of `#subCategory` is entirely generated by your code the first thing you should do is `.empty()` whatever is in it. Otherwise you'll just keep `.append()`-ing more data. https://api.jquery.com/empty/ (This obviously won't work if some of `#subCategory` is static. But this should get you started.)

Answer (score 0):

Mean't to post post this earlier. Figured it out shortly afterwards. It get the job done for me. It is probably not pretty at all.

```
  $(function() {
    $("#service").change(function() {
      var service = $(this).val();
        $.ajax({
          type: "GET",
            url: "<?=Config::get('baseURL');?>getdata.php",
            data: { service: service },
            dataType: "json"
        }).done(function(reply) {
          $("#category").find('option').remove();
          $('#category').append($('<option>').text("--Please Select a Category--"));


            $.each(reply, function(key, value) {   
                $('#category').append($('<option>', { value: value.value }).text(value.text)); 
            });
        });

    });

    $("#category").change(function() {
      var service = $("#service").val();
      var category = $(this).val();
      $.ajax({
          type: "GET",
          url: "<?=Config::get('baseURL');?>getdata.php",
          data: {
              service: service,
              category: category
          },
          dataType: "json"
      }).done(function (reply) {
        $("#subCategory").find('option').remove();

        if (reply.length > 1) {
          $('#subCategory').append($('<option>').text("--Please Select a Sub-Category --"));
          $.each(reply, function (key, value) {
            $("#subCategory").append($('<option>', {
                value: value.value
            }).text(value.text));
          });
        } else {
          var value = reply[0];
          $("#subCategory").append($('<option>', { value: value.value }).text(value.text));

        } 
      });
    });
  });
```